# Compare bash of screenshots

Tags: testing, regression, casperjs

Here is where I am : I want to automate visual regressions. So, with `CasperJS` I took some sample screenshots at multiple sizes. I can use it too to take screenshots of the actual situation. All the screenshots have the same name, there just in two separate folders.

Question is : how can I automate testing? I'm looking for a solution a bit like `compare` from `ImageMagick` which gives me a superposition of the two versions and highlight the difference. But it should works on multiple files.

Any idea ?

Comment: So you want to see all the images at the same time in a big static montage, or one after the other and you press a key to move through them, or in an animation that runs through them automagically changing the image every few seconds?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The way it is presented does not matter to me, as long as I can easily see the differences.

Comment: You're probably looking for resemble.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it something like this in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# These are the FULL paths to the two folders of images - edit as you wish
dir1="/Users/Mark/tmp/A"
dir2="/Users/Mark/tmp/B"
diff="/Users/Mark/tmp/diffs"

# Don't barf if there are no matching files
shopt -s nullglob

# Make output directory
mkdir -p "$diff" 2>/dev/null

cd "$dir1"
for f in *.png *.jpg; do
    echo Processing $f...

    compare "$f" "$dir2/$f" -highlight-color red png:- |
       convert "$f" "$dir2/$f" +append - +append "$diff/$f"

    # DEBUG
    identify "$f" "$dir2/$f" "$diff/$f"
    echo
done
```

This is the original, the second and the difference image for the first file in the folder all three montaged together into a single, wide image that you can flick through in your file browser:

[image]

and this is the original, the second, and the difference image for the second file in the folder, also montaged together into  single, wide image:

[image]

These result images appear in the folder called `diff` and have the same names as the original images.

Comment: Looks good :) But, there is two problems with it : 1) When I fire the script, I have an error for almost every screenshot `Processing 1024-768.png...
montage: unable to open image `/path/to/diff/www-lampiris-be/1024-768.png':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.` 2) For the few one that work, the diff image created is 384 x 126, a bit little for 1xxxpx screenshots

Comment: I have improved the code a little, can you try again please?

Comment: It correctly makes all the diff now. But the diff images are still 384 x 126. Maybe it's a ImageMagick config?

Comment: How big are the originals?

Comment: Depends. It is screenshot at multiple resolution. So, it goes from 320 x 7000 to 1440 x 4650

Comment: I find that hard to imagine - the script does absolutely no resizing at all. I'll edit my answer and put some debugging in there and maybe you can try one more time.

Comment: Sure, here is the output : 

fullpage-600.png PNG 600x5103 600x5103+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.21MB 0.000u 0:00.010
/var/www/test/compare/www-lampiris-be/fullpage-600.png[1] PNG 600x5103 600x5103+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.215MB 0.000u 0:00.000
/var/www/test/diff/www-lampiris-be/fullpage-600.png[2] PNG 384x126 384x126+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 17.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000

Comment: No idea what is going on, but `montage` seems not to be doing what I want, so I have reverted to using `convert` instead. Please try again.

Comment: That seems to work pretty well now! Thank you for all your time :)

Comment: You're welcome - pleased to be of service and sorry it took so long.